# Jenkins sub-domain for each team

Tags: jenkins, subdomain

We are using Jenkins to build our code. Now we have to on-board the external team who add incremental changes/bug fixes to our released codes. We don't want to setup two different Jenkins for each team, instead use the same jenkins with sub-domains for each team so that our UI/dashboard doesn't get cluttered.

Is there any way to create a sub-domain like `http://teamA.myJenkins.com` and `http://teamB.myJenkins.com`?  Or even something like `http://myJenkins.com/teamA`or `http://myJenkins.com/teamB` would do.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Is there a problem in creating `views`?

Comment: @Technext  Yeah that's one way, but I don't want the teams to fiddle with jobs of each other.

Comment: Haven't you enabled `Matrix-based security` or similar stuff?

Comment: Yeah I did, but if I don't provide Overall/Read permission, I'm getting 404 error for user otherwise all the views are shown which defeats my purpose.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your purpose is to segregate views for external teams and at the same time ensuring that the existing team and the external team do not interfere with each other's job's configuration. To implement this, you need to add view (refer screenshot below) and you also need to implement security.

[image: Creating views]

To implement security, go to `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Enable security (Enable check-box)`. Now in `Authorization` section, you can select either `Matrix-based security` or `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` (refer screenshot below). I feel the latter one is what you need because there will be certain jobs which only the external team requires so they should only have rights to build/modify those jobs and not the other ones.

[image: Enabling Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy]

So, once you select `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy`, you will have to go to job's configuration page and select `Enable project-based security` option (refer screenshot below). There you can specify the users who will have access to the given job.

[image: Enable project-based security in job's configuration]